# How to measure page load time in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Previously I've been using a table to log usage and page views in my systems. I'm now writing a system in Phoenix and trying to work out how to best track usage.

Currently I'm using a plug to insert logs. However, I'm unable to track page generation times as the plug is called at the start of the page generation process and I can't find out how to call it at the end.

Is there a way to do this or even better yet a solution I couldn't find in my googling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However, I'm unable to track page generation times as the plug is called at the start of the page generation process and I can't find out how to call it at the end.

You can use [`Plug.Conn.register_before_send/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#register_before_send/2) to execute an `fn` after the page is generated and just before the response is sent. `Plug.Logger` [uses the same](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/50424f928f8d37c553de50cb7a14637a3cc55786/lib/plug/logger.ex#L33) to show the time taken to respond to a request.

```
def call(conn, level) do
  # Executed before the request is processed.
  Conn.register_before_send(conn, fn conn ->
    # Executed after the response is generated.
    conn # Make sure to return the `conn` here.
  end)
end
```

Comment: That's excellent, thanks!

For future reference, where is the best place to find documentation on these things since they're not on the main phoenix guide.

Comment: This function is part of Plug. You can see Plug's documentation here: https://hexdocs.pm/plug (I've also added this link to my answer.)

Comment: Cheers, really appreciate it.